# xaringan set the document title dynamically

Tags: r, dynamic, r-markdown, slideshow, xaringan

In R-markdown there is is an option to move the `title:` out of the main YAML, [as described in the R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/dynamic-yaml.html#dynamic-yaml).

But, in a Xaringan slide set the new `---` seems to conflict with the idea of new slide.

The below code works, but when move line #2, `title: "Presentation Ninja"` outside the main YAML, and inset it as `title: "The name of the dog is` r dog_name`!"`, by removing all my `<!-- ... -->` code in line #17-19, it **does not work** as expected. I do no longer get a title page. I guess I need to work around the `---` in Xaringan?

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
---
# xaringan set the document title dynamically
       
```{r, code=xfun::read_utf8('script_with_many_dog_names.R')}
```

The name of the dog is `r dog_name`!

<!-- --- -->
<!-- title: "The name of the dog is `r dog_name`!" -->
<!-- --- -->

Some bullets

- Foo

- Bar
````

Answer (score 4):

You could use `R Markdown` parameters :

1. Create a template file `Template.Rmd`

```
---
title: "The name of the dog is `r params$dog_name`"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "John Doe"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
params:
    dog_name: NA
---



# xaringan set the document title dynamically

Some bullets

- Foo

- Bar
```

2. Render the template after setting `dog_name` parameter :

```
source('script_with_many_dog_names.R')

# As an example, but it could be the result of previous script
params <- list(dog_name = 'Charles')

rmarkdown::render('Template.Rmd', output_file = 'presentation.html',
                  params = params,
                  envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting workaround, thanks. It does however complicate the case a bit, it could work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I added a possible implementation of the sourcing of your own script. Parameters can be any list which makes the above structure highly customizable. Didn't either find a way to modify directly YAML.

Answer (score 3):

You can add your logic directly to the title, that seems to work fine for me:

```
---
title: "The number is `r round(100 * runif(1), 2)`"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
---
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question! I realize that should have mentioned that I need to use an external variable, that I am sourcing in. Sorry! You do have a vote :)

Comment: Gotcha, sorry I wasn't originally following. Didn't actually realize you can do this, very cool! I can confirm this seems to work for other outputs I'm testing including Powerpoint, but does not work for xaringan template. I think we need the man himself Yihui for this one. I know he goes through all questions tagged with xaringan and other packages he made, but perhaps worth making an issue on GitHub! Happy to help as needed!